# How to saving plots and model results to pdf in python?

Tags: python, plot, model, report

I know how to save model results to .txt files and saving plots to .png. I also found some post which shows how to save multiple plots on a single pdf file. What I am looking for is generating a single pdf file which can contain both model results/summary and it's related plots. So at the end I can have something like auto generated model report. Can someone suggest me how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

I’ve had good results with the fpdf module. It should do everything you need it to do and the learning curve isn’t bad. You can install with pip install fpdf.